# How to repair crack in a pillar exterior panel

Tags: rust, body-work, cracking

I am considering purchasing a 1972 Monte Carlo with a crack in the metal of the a pillar panel. I was wondering if it is possible to repair such damage or if I should avoid this vehicle.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the mad welding skills, this can be repaired. If not, you're looking at a HUGE repair bill. One of the issues here is that the A-pillar is very much structurally important for the vehicle. This area really needs to be done correctly so it will retain it's structural integrity. The glass would need to come out (obviously). You also need to think about what else you'd find which has rusted away inside ... the part you can't see. Considering where it's at and the condition it's in, you can pretty much assume there's been water pouring down the A-pillar when it rains, every time it rains. I'm betting there's a huge amount you can't see.

My opinion? If you don't have the skills to do the work, pass. That is, unless you got some deep pockets.

Comment: PS: I put a 402BBC/TH400 out of 72 Monte into my 72 Chevelle ... that thing was awesome :o)

Comment: I'd be willing to bet the entire car is rust being held together by a small amount of remaining metal.

Comment: Steel does not generally crack like that , rust cracks.

Comment: This type of rust was quite common on GM vehicles of the era. One of the primary causes was the vinyl tops had a cloth backing that retained moisture. Typically the lower corners of the rear windowws suffered the same fate. Check the entire roof and the glass openings before before trying to repair that one spot.